# Entity Framework 4.0 only include some related data

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want my query results to only inlcude some of the reated data. For instatnce say I have the entities Sale and Item with each Sale having an Items property which is a list of Item for a particular Sale:

```
from s in myContext.Sales
select s;
```

returns all Sales with each Sale containing all Items (when I navigate to Items as LazyLoading is on by default). But I want to only include specifc Items for each Sale - say Items where Name == "Orange" and I still want all Sales. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is specific to EF 4.0 and mostly got from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896249.aspx

Prevent LazyLoading loading everything when a navigation property is accessed:

```
myContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Load you items:

```
List<Sale> sales = (from s in myContext.Sales
                    select s).ToList()
```

Foreach item Attach its related items you want (the key to getting only some items is the CreateSourceQuery() method):

```
foreach(Sale s in sales)
    s.Items.Attach(s.Items.CreateSourceQuery().Where(i => i.Name == "Orange"));
```

Answer (score 4):

If lazy loading is on, it will in fact lazily load stuff that you reference.  If you don't want it enabled, then turn it off.

```
myContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

You can specify that you want certain things loaded in the initial database round-trip so that lazy loading is not necessary.  There, *Include* is your friend.

```
using System.Data.Entity; // You need this to get the lambda version of Include

from s in myContext.Sales.Include(s => s.PropertyA).Include(s => s.PropertyB)
select s;
```

Note that you can *always* disable lazy loading for *specific* properties by not declaring them virtual.

I recommend the following blog for a great overview

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: wouldn't the linq you have restrict the Sales returned? i want all sales just each sale with particular items.. is myContext.Sales

Comment: even after including the using System.Data.Entity; I get: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: You also have to reference System.Data.Entity if you aren't already.  Yes, the given Linq statement would restrict the portions of Sales that are returned to the Sales object itself plus anything I include with one or more .Include calls.  If you *don't* want lazy loading, you *do* have to specify up front what you want.

Comment: i have included the reference to System.Data.Entity it still doesnt work. your linq doesnt give what i have asked for. also the hyperlink you posted does have what i want the :"Explicitly loading related entities" part - but that is for EF 4.1, I am only using 4.0 and cannot do that.

Comment: thanks anyway - I found out how to do it EF 4.0 see my answer

Comment: apologies I see now you said "reference" which I read as "using" System.Data.Entity